# How to use points data to plot 2D colorful region image?

Tags: plotting

I have a list data just like following:

```
data={{0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1.}, {0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 
1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 
3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.}};
```

Different number stand for different color, I use `ListPlot3D` plot a 3-d graphic, just like
[image: 3-d plot]

Simple codes:

```
ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> Above]
```

But I only want to show it on 2-d plane, just like [image: what I want]

(colors is not important, just stand for different region)

Is there any way to do it?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html):

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html):

```
ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image]

**Note:** [`ListContourPlot >> Properties and Relations:`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html)

> ListContourPlot *is similar to* ListDensityPlot, *but with bands of discrete colors*.

Comment: Your codes is good, but I don't know why `ListDensityPlot`' is not clear as `ListContourPlot`, and I think color will changed immediately, no "color line" between two colors (`ListContourPlot`), do you thinkd so?

Comment: @zongxian, updated with a link that explains the different looks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use ArrayPlot:

```
ArrayPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1, DataReversed -> True, 
                ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image]

MatrixPlot works similarly, and you can choose from many color schemes.